# How can I select rows from a dataframe that match any of the elements in a vector?

Tags: r

I am using the dataframe below:

```
Product.Name = c('BRILINTA','BRILINTA','Brilinta 6','Brilinta 9')
NDC = c(00186077739,00186077660,00186077739,00186077760)
df = cbind(Product.Name,NDC)
```

I have two lists below:

```
ticagrelor_ndc = c(00186077660,186077739,186077694,186077708,186077760,5515496180,5515496188,6923811346,6923811341)
ticagrelor_name = c('ticagrelor','Brilinta 6','Brilinta 9','Brilinta','BRILINTA')
```

I would like to select the rows from the data frame that have df$Product.Name matches any element in ticagrelor_name or that have df$NDC matches any element in ticagrelor_ndc.

I have tried the following:

```
df[(NDC %in% ticagrelor_ndc) | (Product.Name %in% ticagrelor_name)]
df[sapply(1:nrow(input_data), function(x) all(input_data$NDC %in% ndc_list)),]
subset(df,NDC %in% ndc_list | Product.Name %in% name_list)
```

Actual results:

1) Matching df$Product.Name to ticagrelor_name works perfectly.
2) Matching df$NDC to ticagrelor_ndc does not work at all.

Expected result:
I would like to be able to match based upon df$Product.Name and df$NDC.

Comment: In one part of your post, you say that you want to match "df$Product.Name matches any element in ticagrelor_name OR that have df$NDC matches any element in ticagrelor_ndc".  But later you write: "I would like to be able to match based upon df$Product.Name AND df$NDC"
Which is it?
Also, that's not usually what is meant by providing an expected result.  Actually post the expected lines of output you are hoping to get.  Better still if you can show what gets omitted with a correct filter.

Comment: The problem here is your use of `cbind`. It makes `df` a matrix, not a data frame and so `NDC` is of type character, not numeric. If you just used `df = data.frame(Product.Name = c('BRILINTA','BRILINTA','Brilinta 6','Brilinta 9'),
NDC = c(00186077739,00186077660,00186077739,00186077760), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, you would be able to use _e.g._ `df$NDC` and matching should work.

Comment: Also as @andrew_reece points out, variable names in your example data and code are completely inconsistent.

Comment: Many thanks for your input here. I tried your code on my full dataset and it did not work. I then realized that the NDC column contained mostly numerics but a few characters and that the entire column was imported as character. I adjusted my ticagrelor_ndc = c() so that all elements were character and it worked brilliantly. Thank you. I had been stuck for the past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you actually have a data frame (see @neilfws's comment) and use the OR (`|`) operator in `filter()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(Product.Name %in% ticagrelor_name | NDC %in% ticagrelor_ndc)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Product.Name       NDC
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 BRILINTA     186077739
2 BRILINTA     186077660
3 Brilinta 9   186077760
```

Note: 
Your provided data doesn't actually seem to produce any failed matches - here's a modified dataset to demonstrate how the `"Brilinta 6"` row is filtered out when it doesn't match either `_name` or `_ndc`:

```
Product.Name <- c('BRILINTA','BRILINTA','Brilinta 6','Brilinta 9')
NDC = c(00186077739,00186077660,00186077739,00186077760)
ticagrelor_ndc <- c(00186077660,186077694,186077708, 186077760,
                    5515496180,5515496188,6923811346,6923811341)
ticagrelor_name <- c('ticagrelor','Brilinta 9', 'Brilinta','BRILINTA')
df <- data.frame(Product.Name, NDC)
```